# How to check if a file exists in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a Next.js React website that fetches audio files from an API and stores them locally. However, I would like to check if a files already exists before calling the API to avoid unnecessary API calls. Most solutions on the internet are for Node.js environment but i'm looking for a solution that can work from the client browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the [Origin Private File System (OPFS)](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/origin-private-file-system/).  See also: [What technologies store data in the browser?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API/Storage_quotas_and_eviction_criteria#what_technologies_store_data_in_the_browser)

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please provide more details on what do you mean " store them locally ". So I can edit my answer and help you.

Comment: @araldhafeeri I ended up checking for the file on the server using 'fs' so no help needed. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Since next.js is based on node js run time you can use fs module specifically existsSync

Which is a synchronous method that allows you to check if file exists.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = './someFile.txt';

if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
  console.log('file exists');
}
```

Comment: The question literally says, _"i'm looking for a solution that can work from the client browser"_

Comment: Yes I can read the question which does not make sense. JavaScript running in the browser have limited access to the local file system due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you have no access to the file system in the browser environment. otherwise

- Websites could read files containing sensitive information,
- websites could inject or download malicious files
- websites could delete system files
- websites could gain your personal information

etc.

React.js itself does not provide direct file system access capabilities. what you could do is store the file names in a hash set on the server and when your app loads, you fetch that data (maybe create a listener), store it in your react state system and before you make request, you check this state on the client side